# Fastest way to find nearest triangle number?

Tags: python

In python I need a function that takes an integer and returns the absolute value of n minus the nearest [triangle number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) to n. The way I'm doing it now is by generating a list of all the triangle numbers up to n. 
Then using:

```
def closest(myList, myNumber):
    c = min(myList, key=lambda x:abs(x-myNumber))
```

To find the closest triangle number.

The end result list should look like:

```
[0, 0, 1 , 0 , 1 ,1 , 0 , 1, 2 , 1, 0 , 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, etc.]
```

If you have another method of generating the same result that's faster go for it.

Comment: What is a Triangle number?

Comment: @thefourtheye My guess is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number, as this comes up in coding exercises.

Comment: The index of the nth number in the list, if that makes any sense. So F(8) would return 2.

Comment: if you want the nearest triangle number, shouldn't it return 1 or 3 for an input of 2?

Comment: It should return the `absolute value of the difference between n and the nearest triangle number to n`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little bit of math will bring a more analytical solution:

```
from math import sqrt
def close_triangle2(n):
    m=int(0.5*(-1+sqrt(1+8*n))) #solve it for the explicit formula
    tan0=(m*m+m)/2              #the closest one is either this
    tan1=(m*m+3*m+2)/2          #or this
    if (n-tan0)>(tan1-n):
        return tan1-n
    else:
        return n-tan0
```

It will become slightly faster than the loop version from @perreal when the number is large:

```
In [87]:

%timeit close_triangle(111111111)
100000 loops, best of 3: 5 µs per loop
In [86]:

%timeit close_triangle2(111111111)
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.13 µs per loop
```

If you wonders:

```
In [94]:

close_triangle2((30**10 * (30**10+1)) / 2 + 100)
Out[94]:
100L
In [95]:

close_triangle((30**10 * (30**10+1)) / 2 + 100)
Out[95]:
100L

In [102]:

%timeit close_triangle((30**10 * (30**10+1)) / 2 + 100)
10000 loops, best of 3: 17.9 µs per loop
In [103]:

%timeit close_triangle2((30**10 * (30**10+1)) / 2 + 100)
100000 loops, best of 3: 12 µs per loop
```

Comment: Interesting, I would have thought it was the triangle root that was causing the numerical instability in my solution, but it looks like it was calculating the actual triangle number, since the only difference in our solutions is that you do that using a floored int instead of a rounded float.

Comment: This also does eventually run into limits if the float portion exceeds a 64bit double, try ``close_triangle2((1000**10 * (1000**10+1)) / 2 + 100)``, which returns ``-19884624838656000197699152487057519328362396L``. But that's going to happen eventually if you ever use a float, and there's no way other than successive approximation to calculate this using purely ints.

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage the *triangle-root* property to quickly calculate the nearest triangle number to a number, and from there easily calculate your value

```
from math import sqrt

def triangle_number(tnumber):
    '''
    returns the tnumberth triangle number (I.E 3 = 6)
    '''
    return (tnumber*(tnumber+1))/2

def triangle_root(number):
    '''
    returns the triangle root of a number (I.E 6 = 3)
    '''
    return (sqrt(8*number+1)-1)/2

def nearest_root(number):
    '''
    Calculates the nearest whole triangle root to a number (I.E. 5 = 3)
    '''
    t_root = triangle_root(number)
    return round(t_root)

def find_delta(number):
    '''
    Given a number, returns abs(n-nearest_triangle)
    '''
    return abs(number - triangle_number(nearest_root(number)))
```

Of course you could condense this into a single function for efficiency, I just spaced it out for clarity.

Comment: Why does this give 0.0 for `find_delta((30**10 * (30**10+1)) / 2 + 100)`?

Comment: Because that is apparently the ``590490000000000.0`` triangle number. Which is likely a numerical stability problem, unless it was really that lucky.

Comment: Testing it, yeah, it's definitely a numerical stability problem. Removing the ``+100`` results in the same triangle root. So this solution is definitely limited by the precision of floating point math for very large triangle numbers (which is to be expected since it has a sqrt). We'd have to bench to see if successive approximation or direct calculation was more efficient for small numbers.

Answer (score 2):

In my solution I have used the fact that 
let K = sqrt(2*N)
 if N is a triangular number then it will be Kth triangular number
We know Kth triangular number will be K*(K+1)/2

Here is my solution in Python

```
from math import sqrt
from math import floor
def close_triangle(n):
m = floor(sqrt(2*n))
t1 = m*(m+1)/2       #next triangular number to n
m = m-1
t2 = m*(m+1)/2       #previous triangular number to n
diff1 = t1-n
diff2 = n - t2
if diff1 < diff2 :
  return t1
else:
  return t2
print "Nearest trianguler number";
print close_triangle(13)
```

Answer (score 1):

May not be the best way but should be faster than your method:

```
def triangle_around(n):
    k = int((2*n)**0.5)
    p = (k**2 + k) / 2 
    while p < n:
        k, p = k + 1, p + k + 1 
    return (p - k, p)

def close_triangle(n):
    t = triangle_around(n)
    return min(t[1] - n, n - t[0])

print close_triangle(8)    # gives 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have one solution that doesn't need calculate every triangle number first, but I am not sure whether it's best.

As formula of triange number is

```
    A(n) = n*(n-1)/2       (n is integer)
```

For input x, it should be in middle of A(n) and A(n+1)

```
    A(n) <= x <= A(n+1)
```

For A(n) we have:

```
    n * (n - 1) / 2 <= x
    (n - 1)^2 < n * (n-1) <= 2*x
    n < sqrt(2*x) + 1
```

For A(n+1) we have:

```
    (n + 1)^2 > (n + 1) * n >= 2*x
    n > sqrt(2*x) - 1
```

Now, if we have input number x, we could rapidly find n that makes x in [A(n),A(n+1)], then we only need to calculate distance of [abs(A(n) - x),abs(A(n+1) - x)] and make smallar one as real output.